# Graphical issue with Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, visual-artifacts

I'm having some strange graphical issue with windows manager in Kubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Some time after I'm using the system i notice some artifacts that affects windows. I'm attaching some examples

[image]

[image]

This make the system unusable: for example if I click on a icon in Dolphin the icons of the "parent" folder does not disappear and overlaps with the icons of the folder I just clicked.

### I wasn't able to isolate what causes this behaviour: when I start the system it works just fine, then after some time happens what is shown in the images.

Edit: 
This issue happened again, I noticed it when the pc was running for 3 hours. 
Thanks ellisistfroh, I launched on a terminal the commands that you suggested. It does not look like a Xorg problem. I don't think is an overheating problem because if I logout/login the problem disappears. I also tried to restart KWin but with no success.

```
$ egrep "EE|WW" /var/log/Xorg.*
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.758] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.774] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.774] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[     5.774] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
/var/log/Xorg.0.log:[   221.844] (WW) EDID timing clock 328.32 exceeds claimed max 145MHz, fixing
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.546] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.546] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.547] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.547] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.547] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.549] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.553] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.553] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1541.553] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  1550.426] (WW) EDID timing clock 328.32 exceeds claimed max 145MHz, fixing
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old:[  6081.944] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0d7]
        Kernel driver in use: i915

$ tail -n 50 ~/.xsession-errors
Script for none started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
```

Edit2: 
I didn't specified that the GPU is an HD3000 (Intel integrated)
Other info

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

$ uname -a
Linux mypc 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg-query -l xserver-xorg-core* | grep ^ii
ii  xserver-xorg-core                     2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 

$ dpkg-query -l *-lts-* | grep ^ii
(No info)

$ qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin supportInformation
KWin Support Information:
The following information should be used when requesting support on e.g. http://forum.kde.org.
It provides information about the currently running instance, which options are used,
what OpenGL driver and which effects are running.
Please post the information provided underneath this introductory text to a paste bin service
like http://paste.kde.org instead of pasting into support threads.

==========================

Version
=======
KWin version: 4.11.11
KDE SC version (runtime): 4.13.3
KDE SC version (compile): 4.13.2
Qt Version: 4.8.6

Options
=======
focusPolicy: 0
nextFocusPrefersMouse: false
clickRaise: true
autoRaise: false
autoRaiseInterval: 0
delayFocusInterval: 0
shadeHover: false
shadeHoverInterval: 250
separateScreenFocus: false
placement: 4
focusPolicyIsReasonable: true
borderSnapZone: 10
windowSnapZone: 10
centerSnapZone: 0
snapOnlyWhenOverlapping: false
showDesktopIsMinimizeAll: false
rollOverDesktops: true
focusStealingPreventionLevel: 1
legacyFullscreenSupport: false
operationTitlebarDblClick: 
commandActiveTitlebar1: 0
commandActiveTitlebar2: 30
commandActiveTitlebar3: 2
commandInactiveTitlebar1: 4
commandInactiveTitlebar2: 30
commandInactiveTitlebar3: 2
commandWindow1: 7
commandWindow2: 8
commandWindow3: 8
commandWindowWheel: 31
commandAll1: 10
commandAll2: 3
commandAll3: 14
keyCmdAllModKey: 16777251
showGeometryTip: false
condensedTitle: false
electricBorderMaximize: true
electricBorderTiling: true
electricBorderCornerRatio: 0.25
borderlessMaximizedWindows: false
killPingTimeout: 5000
hideUtilityWindowsForInactive: true
inactiveTabsSkipTaskbar: false
autogroupSimilarWindows: false
autogroupInForeground: true
compositingMode: 1
useCompositing: true
compositingInitialized: true
hiddenPreviews: 1
unredirectFullscreen: false
glSmoothScale: 2
colorCorrected: false
xrenderSmoothScale: false
maxFpsInterval: 16666666
refreshRate: 0
vBlankTime: 6000000
glDirect: true
glStrictBinding: false
glStrictBindingFollowsDriver: true
glLegacy: false
glCoreProfile: false
glPreferBufferSwap: 101

Screen Edges
============
desktopSwitching: false
desktopSwitchingMovingClients: false
cursorPushBackDistance: 
timeThreshold: 150
reActivateThreshold: 350
actionTopLeft: 0
actionTop: 0
actionTopRight: 0
actionRight: 0
actionBottomRight: 0
actionBottom: 0
actionBottomLeft: 0
actionLeft: 0

Screens
=======
Multi-Head: no
Active screen follows mouse:  no
Number of Screens: 2
Screen 0 Geometry: 0,0,1366x768
Screen 1 Geometry: 1366,0,1280x1024

Decoration
==========
Current Plugin: kwin3_oxygen
Shadows: yes
Alpha: yes
Announces Alpha: yes
Tabbing: yes
Frame Overlap: no
Blur Behind: no

Compositing
===========
Qt Graphics System: raster
Compositing is active
Compositing Type: OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
Driver: Intel
GPU class: IvyBridge
OpenGL version: 3.0
GLSL version: 1.30
Mesa version: 10.1.3
X server version: 1.15.1
Linux kernel version: 3.13
Direct rendering: yes
Requires strict binding: no
GLSL shaders:  yes
Texture NPOT support:  yes
Virtual Machine:  no
OpenGL 2 Shaders are used
Painting blocks for vertical retrace:  no

Loaded Effects:
---------------
kwin4_effect_zoom
kwin4_effect_slidingpopups
kwin4_effect_login
kwin4_effect_minimizeanimation
kwin4_effect_screenshot
kwin4_effect_slide
kwin4_effect_desktopgrid
kwin4_effect_translucency
kwin4_effect_maximize
kwin4_effect_fade
kwin4_effect_highlightwindow
kwin4_effect_taskbarthumbnail
kwin4_effect_dialogparent
kwin4_effect_presentwindows
kwin4_effect_blur
kwin4_effect_logout
kwin4_effect_dashboard
kwin4_effect_screenedge
kwin4_effect_startupfeedback
kwin4_effect_kscreen

Currently Active Effects:
-------------------------
kwin4_effect_blur

Effect Settings:
----------------
kwin4_effect_zoom:
zoomFactor: 1.2
mousePointer: 0
mouseTracking: 0
enableFocusTracking: false
followFocus: true
focusDelay: 350
moveFactor: 20
targetZoom: 1

kwin4_effect_slidingpopups:
fadeInTime: 250
fadeOutTime: 250

kwin4_effect_login:

kwin4_effect_minimizeanimation:

kwin4_effect_screenshot:

kwin4_effect_slide:

kwin4_effect_desktopgrid:
zoomDuration: 300
border: 10
desktopNameAlignment: 0
layoutMode: 0
customLayoutRows: 2
usePresentWindows: true

kwin4_effect_translucency:

kwin4_effect_maximize:

kwin4_effect_fade:

kwin4_effect_highlightwindow:

kwin4_effect_taskbarthumbnail:

kwin4_effect_dialogparent:

kwin4_effect_presentwindows:
layoutMode: 0
showCaptions: true
showIcons: true
doNotCloseWindows: false
ignoreMinimized: false
accuracy: 20
fillGaps: true
fadeDuration: 150
showPanel: false
leftButtonWindow: 1
rightButtonWindow: 2
middleButtonWindow: 0
leftButtonDesktop: 2
middleButtonDesktop: 0
rightButtonDesktop: 0
dragToClose: false

kwin4_effect_blur:
blurRadius: 12
cacheTexture: true

kwin4_effect_logout:
useBlur: true

kwin4_effect_dashboard:
brightness: 0.5
saturation: 0.5
blur: false

kwin4_effect_screenedge:

kwin4_effect_startupfeedback:

kwin4_effect_kscreen:
```

Edit 3:
As suggested by @ellisfroth I installed openjdk-6. I was experiencing this issue this morning and the problem solved without rebooting.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre  openjdk-6-jdk

$ dpkg-query -l openjdk-* | grep ^ii
ii  openjdk-6-jdk:amd64                   6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-6-jre:amd64                   6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64          6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-6-jre-lib                     6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              all          OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
ii  openjdk-7-jdk:amd64                   7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1             amd64        OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
ii  openjdk-7-jre:amd64                   7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1             amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
ii  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64          7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1             amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)

$ dpkg-query -l icedtea* | grep ^ii
ii  icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64             6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
ii  icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64             6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04              amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
ii  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64             7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1             amd64        Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
ii  icedtea-netx:amd64                    1.5-1ubuntu1                            amd64        NetX - implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP)
ii  icedtea-netx-common                   1.5-1ubuntu1                            all          NetX - implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP)
```

Comment: would be useful to me to know why this has been downvoted so I can improve questions I will do in the future. Thanks

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, but I don't think it deserved it. By any chance do you use Chrome? I'm experiencing a simlar thing in GNOME, only when using Chrome. Might be unrelated though.

Comment: @kos Yes i use chrome, version 46.0.2490.86. When the problem happens chrome is opened, but has been opened for a while, not when I first open chrome. The browser is the first thing I open after the Terminal :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could as well be this bug (see also bug-duplicates there):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1512760
 title: Java applications leaks shmem chunks

See also: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=799587#20 which is the reference for Debian

If the error appeared out of nowwhere (missing info from u), this can come from a messy update.

You can justify this by looking into your APT-History:
 `$`var/log/apt/history.log

`$`java -version

tells what the installed version is. Awaiting reply from you...

Comment: what happens to me correspond to the issue reported in that bug report

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add OpenJDK-6-JRE and select this than via the alternatives system. Since u cannot install OpenJDK-8 to solve this & OpenJRE-6 doesn't seem to be affected. Saying so from looking at the changelogs

just run `dpkg-query -l openjdk-* | grep ^ii` and for the browser-plugin `dpkg-query -l icedtea* | grep ^ii` Post the result here, as ur question has now sufficient content, to my mind.

Comment: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6_6b36-1.13.8-0ubuntu1~14.04/changelog

Comment: Hi, I attached the output of the commands in my question (I didn't have enought characters to insert it as comment) but it seems solved by installing openjdk-6.

Comment: Once the fix arrives for OpenJDK-7 (which might take a while in (K)Ubuntu) u should just remove OpenJDK-6 and Icedtea-6. The alternatives-system will automatically shift. The next higher solution would have been to use the ppa-version for testing & feedback as suggested in comment# 14 in LP-bug-report #1512760 Remember that the solution we found is only a _workaround_

Answer (score 1):

If the issue remains, we should take a look into log-files in order to find errors via Terminal/Konsole (just C&P the commands):

`egrep "EE|WW" /var/log/Xorg.0.log*`

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`

`tail -n 50 ~/.xsession-errors`

It's senseless to make guesses out of nowwhere. It could even be an effect of overheating or the signs of a dieing graphis-card. Check ventilators for dust! Or *some* PPA.

O.k. Since we know now it's hybrid graphics Laptop with a 
Intel HD4000 / Nvidia GT650M - we need more Information:

`uname -a`

`dpkg-query -l xserver-xorg-core* | grep ^ii`

`dpkg-query -l *-lts-* | grep ^ii`

`qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin supportInformation`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with the output of the commands you suggested to run

Comment: Editet my answer to come to a higher level of knowledge regards your laptop. Is this an update from a previous version or a new installation? Do you use Prime or Bumblebee to switch the graphics-card?

Comment: It has only one GPU (HD3000).