# Menus and icons don't display on Kubuntu

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kubuntu, 64-bit, kde

Since few days (maybe since mid-Nov 2015) my KDE display shows strange behaviours. With some menus, the items don't show, I can only read them if I hover the mouse over them. The characters are very ugly and bold. But this occurs only with menus like the system menu or some menus like those in Konsole/Kate. With other applications like Firefox or NetBeans there seems to be no problem.

I'm currently running on Kubuntu **12.04.5 LTS**.

The kernel is **3.2.0-61 generic** on a x86-64 (Quad core I7).

KDE version is **4.8.5**

My video setup is a **GeForce GTS 450** with NVidia driver **304.131**.

Notice that I apply the updates as soon as they are available.

I would like to know what happens because it is very anoying. I tried to erase the *.kde* folder but nothing changed... I don't suspect my video board because the problem occurs only with some menus. I rather suspect KDE...??????

Do you have an idea to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Dominique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be the outcome of a Java OpenJDK7-bug. 
Possible reference:
[Question 697515 Graphical Issues with Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697515/graphical-issue-with-kubuntu)

Comment: After reading the link you suggest, I found it looks very like my problem. I will try the solutions tonight when I will have my computer. Note that I could not guess that it could be linked to Java... ;-)

Comment: Do u need further help? Don't mind asking here! Remember: Publishing a solution may help others who suffer the same problem...

Comment: I did what you suggested. It seems to solve my problem but I want to test it for more than two hours before being more affirmative.

Comment: Testing a little longer is always o.k. & preferred.

Comment: Thanks ellisistfroh, you gave me the solution! After more than three hours, no more display problem occurred. I believe the JDK was the problem.

Comment: Happy 2help You